# Using a forked and modified version of R GitHub repo

Tags: r, github

I have forked a GitHub repo of an R library and edited some functionalities as per my requirements. I now want to use this new library and its functions in my R script. Is there a way to do this?

I read this https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/githubinstall/vignettes/githubinstall.html

For ex:

I have forked and edited the repo package `textshaping` and I want to use this newly edited version something like:

```
library(username/textshaping)
username/textshaping::text_width("Seven sea\'s seacod")
```

Comment: You should just be able to use the `remotes` package and install with `remotes::install_github("username/package")`.  where `username` is the GitHub username of the person hosting the repo and `package` is the name of the repository.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. But how do I use this new package in my script? I have edited my question above.

Comment: Once you've installed it, you could just do: `library(textshaping)` and then use `text_width("Seven sea\'s seacod")`.  When you install the `textshaping` package from GitHub it will replace whatever version of that same package exists on your system (if you've installed it already from CRAN or something). Then you can use it just like any other package.